# Calling a method from Activity2 in Activity1

Tags: android, class, methods, android-activity

I have two classes/Activities:

*FirstClass:*

```
public class FirstClass extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
  public void addData(String filename, String data); {
    SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
    second.save(name, data);
  }
}
```

*SecondClass:*

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
  public void save(String filename, String data) {
    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      fos.write(data.getBytes());
      fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, what I want to do is to call a method from `SecondClass` in `FirstClass`. The method savse some data to the internal storage.

What is the correct way of doing this? I know i should probably do something with `Context`, but i don't know what exactly.

Comment: You not try to couple activities together.  Create a 3rd class, put the method in there and have each activity call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it as a simple java class.

```
public class ThirdClass
{
    public void save(String filename, String data, Context context)
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Call this method like in your First Activity.

```
ThirdClass third= new ThirdClass();
third.save(name, data,this);
```

Alternative If you don't want to make the Third class and want to do with SecondClass. Then make this save method to static.

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity
{
    //Oncreate method....

    public static void save(String filename, String data)
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and Call this method from First Activity.

```
SecondClass.save(name, data);
```

Comment: Doing that prohibits me from using FileOutputStream. Give the following error:The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type HighScoreHandler

Comment: @MeesterPatat, you can always pass ApplicationContext to the constructor of the class.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution.

Comment: if i apply this i get an error of IlleagalArgumentException: File contains a path seperator.. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

make `save` a static method and/or move it to its own static class (not activity).

So you can call it using the following:

```
SecondClass.save(name, data);
```

and define it as the following:

```
public static void save(String filename, String data)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class named something like SaveHelper, that doesn't extend activity and add a static method so you can do:
    FileHelper.save(...)

```
public class FileHelper {
public static void save(Context context, String filename, String data) {
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  fos.write(data.getBytes());
  fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}